# Rademacher complexity: $R(cA)=\vert c\vert R(A)?$ (where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^m$)

Tags: real-analysis, machine-learning

I have a question about Lemma 26.6 of the book, "Understanding machine learning," by Shalev-Shwartz and Ben-David, (online version: https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/copy.html)

> **Lemma 26.6** $\quad$ For any $A\subset \mathbb R^m, c\in \mathbb R$ and $\mathbf a_0\in \mathbb R^m$, we have
>   $$R(\{c\mathbf a+\mathbf a_0:\mathbf a\in A\})\le \vert c\vert R(A),$$

where $R(\cdot)$ denotes the Rademacher complexity of a set, i.e. $$R(A)=\frac{1}{m}\underset{\pmb \sigma\sim \{\pm1\}^m }{\mathbb E}\sup_{\mathbf a\in A} \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_ia_i,$$

where $\sigma_i$'s (components of $\pmb \sigma$) are i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $\{-1, +1\}$.  My question: Isn't the inequality above in fact an equality, i.e.

$$R(\{c\mathbf a+\mathbf a_0:\mathbf a\in A\})= \vert c\vert R(A)?$$

---

For simplicity, let's consider $R(\{c\mathbf a:\mathbf a\in A\})$ and denote $\{c\mathbf a:\mathbf a\in A\}$ by $cA$.  I think $R(cA)=\vert c\vert R(A)$.  I argue as follows:

First of all, if $c>0$, clearly $R(cA)=cR(A)$, since
$$R(cA)=\frac{1}{m}\underset{\pmb \sigma\sim \{\pm1\}^m }{\mathbb E}\sup_{\mathbf a\in A} \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i(ca_i)=\frac{1}{m}\underset{\pmb \sigma\sim \{\pm1\}^m }{\mathbb E}c\left (\sup_{\mathbf a\in A} \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i a_i\right)=cR(A).$$

So the claim holds, if $R(-A)=R(A)$.  But this is true, because

$$\begin{align*}R(-A)&=\frac{1}{m}\underset{\pmb \sigma\sim \{\pm1\}^m }{\mathbb E}\sup_{\mathbf a\in A} \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i(-a_i)
\\ &=\frac{1}{m}\underset{\pmb \sigma\sim \{\pm1\}^m }{\mathbb E}\sup_{\mathbf a\in A} \sum_{i=1}^m (-\sigma_i)a_i \\
&= R(A),\end{align*}$$

since $\sigma_i$'s are i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $\{-1, +1\}$.  Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’re correct.

Comment: @J.G I appreciate your comment.